# I updated my version of php and got error

Tags: php

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "Twenty_Eleven_Ephemera_Widget" not found in /home/stag1ngwp/public_html/dev/artpaints/wp-includes/class-wp-widget-factory.php:62 Stack trace:
#0 /home/stag1ngwp/public_html/dev/artpaints/wp-includes/widgets.php(115): WP_Widget_Factory->register()
#1 /home/stag1ngwp/public_html/dev/artpaints/wp-content/themes/artpaints/functions.php(389): register_widget()
#2 /home/stag1ngwp/public_html/dev/artpaints/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(308): twentyeleven_widgets_init()
#3 /home/stag1ngwp/public_html/dev/artpaints/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(332): WP_Hook->apply_filters()
#4 /home/stag1ngwp/public_html/dev/artpaints/wp-includes/plugin.php(517): WP_Hook->do_action()
#5 /home/stag1ngwp/public_html/dev/artpaints/wp-includes/widgets.php(1854): do_action()
#6 /home/stag1ngwp/public_html/dev/artpaints/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(308): wp_widgets_init()
#7 /home/stag1ngwp/public_html/dev/artpaints/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(332): WP_Hook->apply_filters()
#8 /home/stag1ngwp/public_html/dev/artpaints/wp-includes/plugin.php(517): WP_Hook->do_action()
#9 /home/stag1ngwp/public_html/dev/artpaints/wp-settings.php(623): do_action()
#10 /home/stag1ngwp/public_html/dev/artpaints/wp-config.php(93): require_once('/home/stag1ngwp...')
#11 /home/stag1ngwp/public_html/dev/artpaints/wp-load.php(50): require_once('/home/stag1ngwp...')
#12 /home/stag1ngwp/public_html/dev/artpaints/wp-blog-header.php(13): require_once('/home/stag1ngwp...')
#13 /home/stag1ngwp/public_html/dev/artpaints/index.php(17): require('/home/stag1ngwp...')
#14 {main} thrown in /home/stag1ngwp/public_html/dev/artpaints/wp-includes/class-wp-widget-factory.php on line 62
```

Comment: First thing first would be to check if your theme or wordpress version can run on your new PHP version. Can you give us your WordPress version and PHP version?

Comment: Php version old is 7.4 and the new one is 8.1

Comment: WordPress is  6.2

Comment: you've tagged your questions as wordpress.com hosting, is this a mistake? If you are a customer of wordpress.com you need to contact their support rather than asking here, but if you are not a customer of wordpress.com you should remove that tag

Comment: also you should update plugins and themes _before_ upgrading PHP, is the twentyeleven theme up to date?

Comment: It is a 2011 theme customized when I install a fresh 2011 theme it works well, but some of my customizations are lost like color, position, etc, but working nice all widgets everything ok, possible to only cutout customization from the 2011 old custom edited theme and ad it to fresh one?

Comment: If your theme was designed in 2011, it is possible that some PHP functions or code would not work in 2023 with PHP 8.1. You should try to check for compatibilities before updating to 8.1